# Hibernate: Mapping of money type in an hbm.xml file

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, bigdecimal

in my (Microsoft SQL Server) Database I have a table with a column of type money.
As annotation in the class I have:

```
@Column(name = "preis", columnDefinition = "money", nullable=true)
private BigDecimal price;
```

This works well. But how could I do such a mapping in an hbm.xml file?

```
 <property name = "price" column = "EPreis" type="big_decimal"/>
```

Delivers an error:

```
Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column ...
found [money (Types#DECIMAL)], but expecting [numeric(19,2) (Types#NUMERIC)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `sql-type="money"` in your property definition.